# Spring Boot MultiPart file upload blank screen

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm using spring boot (1.5) spring (4.3) FreeMarker, embedded Tomcat.
I want upload file. This is working. I want the max file size to be 10 MB and when the user tries to upload a bigger file to show message.

in the application.properties I have:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

The controller looks like:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFiles(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile,
                          @RequestParam("overwrite") Optional<Boolean> overwrite,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, ModelMap map) throws IOException {
    String referer = map.get(BaseController.REFERER).toString();
    if (uploadedFile.isEmpty()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "message.file.upload.missing.file");
        return "redirect:" + referer;
    }
    if (uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename().length() > 75) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("warning", "message.file.upload.big.title");
        return "redirect:" + referer;
    }
    try {
        fileService.write(referer, uploadedFile, overwrite.isPresent() ? overwrite.get() : Boolean.FALSE);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "message.file.upload.successful");
    } catch (CustomFileException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().contains("message."))
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        else
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "message.file.upload.unsuccessful");
    }
    return "redirect:" + referer;
}
```

I made controllerAdvices(because I expected at least the MultipartException to be called. but it is not called.
[image]

The  template looks like this:

```
  <form name="uploadingForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${base}/upload" method="POST">
    <p>
    <div><input id="fileInput" type="file" name="uploadedFile"></div>
    <div style="padding-top:20px" id="selectedFiles"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="overwrite" value="true">rewrite<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload files">
    </p>
</form>
<div>
    <div>Uploaded files:</div>
    <#list uploadedFiles as file>
        <div>
            <a href="http://localhost:8082/funding/file/getFile/${file.getName()}/${file.getId()?c}">${file.getName()}</a>

            <span>type</span><span>${file.getExtension()}</span>
            <span>size</span><span>${file.getSize()}</span>
            <span>version</span><span>${file.getVersion()}</span>
            <span>version</span><span>${file.getCreatedDate()?date}</span>
            <span>version</span><span>${file.getModifiedDate()?date}</span>

            <a href="http://localhost:8082/funding/file/delete/${file.getId()?c}">delete</a>

        </div>
    </#list>

</div>
```

[image]

When I want to upload a file below 10MB I have no problems and my controller is called. If I want to upload larger file I don't have any exception just this:
[image]

A have empty page.The controller is not called at all.The ControllerAdvice is not called, too.
I tried to debug without success. In some way I think that the request is not send to the end point. but from the last screenshot you can see that it is with 200 status.

I'm using the  standart MultipartResolver.

Thank you.

At the end after a long debugging the problem was connected with the csrf token, which I was using. In some way it was not provided to the request.

Comment: What happens if you test with a different browser?

Comment: The same with Firefox. I was trying with Chrome till now

Comment: Can you please replace the source code screenshots with actual code? I'd like to try it locally.

Comment: From Rest client your ControllerAdvice is working fine if I upload more than 10mb file..as i checked ..